# Keep excerpt from stripping URLs and enable autoembed for youtube ONLY?

Tags: excerpt, oembed

Is there an easy way to drop something into functions? I tried removing all filters from the_excerpt and the URLs are still being stripped (not links, but just straight URLs). I've scoured the repository and haven't found anything addressing this spec issue.

Comment: why do you need to keep url on excerpt area?

Comment: For informational display and user reference. It would also be nice if I could autoembed just the URLs with youtube as a provider, but if I enable autoembed on the_excerpt, it enables all providers :/

Comment: perhaps this can help you
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/43697/show-video-in-excerpt

Comment: Thank you, already tried that... zero effect. As well as removing all filters totally. I'm able to call the video embed in the excerpt by enabling autoembed, but that makes every embeddable URL an embed, which is no bueno. It's also stripping out youtube links from my excerpt. Shucks.

Comment: this plugin seems to do things you need, try it out
https://wordpress.org/plugins/featured-video-plus/

Comment: I do really appreciate your help. I checked out that plugin as well. Right now, the only way I can get past the URL stripping filter is disguising the URL with https:<em>//</em>